# socat - terminate on STDIN EOF while using fork option

Tags: socat

I'm using **socat** to publish data from stdin on a port. In brief:

```
some_process | socat -u - tcp-listen:8888,reuseaddr,fork
```

I want the pipeline to stay alive as readers on port 8888 come and go, hence the **fork** option, but I also want **socat** to terminate if **some_process** dies. Currently it stays alive in that case also.

A simple test case is:

```
while : ; do echo 1; sleep 1; done | socat -u - tcp-listen:8888,reuseaddr,fork
```

which gives this process tree (via pstree):

```
bash─┬─bash───sleep
     └─socat
```

If I kill the second bash (which is running the while loop) then I get:

```
bash───socat
```

I want **socat** to have terminated also. Is what I want possible?

Answer (score 2):

To answer my own question, it looks like what I want is not possible.

From the documentation (xio.help):

> Option: fork
>
> Without fork (or fork=0), the listening process accepts exactly one
>   connections, and terminates afterwards. With fork set, it forks off a
>   new socat child process for each incoming connection.
>
> The parent process remains in a loop of accept() and fork() calls until
>   terminated from outside.

I worked around the issue by connecting my two processes with a FIFO:

```
mkfifo /tmp/myfifo
socat -u - tcp-listen:8888,reuseaddr,fork < /tmp/myfifo &
socat_pid=$!
some_process > /tmp/myfifo
(some_process terminates for some reason)
kill $socat_pid
rm /tmp/myfifo
```